# How to customize border radius of MDBootstrap modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [MDBootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/) in my project & having trouble to customize the border radius of MDBootstrap modal.

I want to make `border-radius: 0` for my modal.

My html code:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicExample" id="modalBtn">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade right" id="basicExample" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-full-height modal-right" role="document">
        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!--Header-->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <!--Body-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <!--Footer-->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
```

I tried:

```
.modal{
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

But it doesn't work properly.
I'm attaching images so that you can understand.[image]

I also tried:

```
.modal{
    border-radius: 25% !important;
}
```

But it works thus:[image]

Comment: can u share your code, do u have any live link

Comment: By the screenshots, you are clearly targeting the wrong element.

Comment: I don't have any live link. But I'm sharing my html & css code

Comment: I don't understand @MrLister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are targeting wrong selector instead you should use below code to reset border of modal

```
.modal-content{
      border-radius: 0;
}
```